# How to run a command after Tailwind JIT compiler ran a build in watch mode?

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-3

**Context:** I need to run a command every time Tailwind's just-in-time compiler ran a new build in watch mode. To be more specific, I need to rebuild Drupal's cache for the changes to take effect.

Unfortunately, watching for modifications of `output.css` with `inotifywait` doesn't work because the JIT compiler doesn't recreate `output.css` in all circumstances. For example, if you add the `border-2` class for the first time, a new version of `output.css` is built. However, if you remove `border-2` again, the compiler won't recreate `output.css` for legitimate reasons. See [JIT compilation doesn't remove unused classes when the DOM changes · Issue #57 · tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-jit](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-jit/issues/57).

I also tried using **tee** and watching the output file with `inotifywait` without success. `npx tailwindcss -i input.css -o output.css --watch | tee tailwind-built` doesn't write to `tailwind-built` for reasons I don't get.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based on **tee** finally.

Problem was that Tailwind's CLI at the time of writing uses `console.error` (see [here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/122fb89e6c49a9d0d36c4fcdb57f9f2c39de7fc6/src/cli.js#L688)) to report

> Rebuilding...
>
> Done in 33ms.

So `npx tailwindcss -i input.css -o output.css --watch 2>&1 | tee tailwind-built` (added `2>&1`) and watching `tailwind-built` with `inotifywait` does the trick.